# R finding the first value in a data frame that falls within a given threshold

Tags: r, subset, threshold

I am a fairly new user and I need your help with a task that I am stuck on. If my question has been asked/answered before I would be grateful if you could kindly guide me to the relevant page.

I have the following data set (lbnp_br) which is optical density (OD) measured over time (in seconds):

```
 time   OD
1891    -244.6
1891.5  -244.4
1892    -242
1892.5  -242
1893    -241.1
1893.5  -242.4
1894    -245.2
1894.5  -249.6
**1895  -253.9**
1895.5  -254.5
1896    -251.9
1896.5  -246.7
1897    -242.4
1897.5  -234.6
1898    -225.5
```

I need to find out how responsive the study device is by measuring how long it takes to reach the threshold for optical density.

For this I have calculated the coefficient of variation (CV) of OD and I am using mean OD (-252.9098) +/- 2*CV to define a response threshold. For the above data the threshold is set as (mean OD + 2*CV = -252.9917), and (mean OD - 2*CV = -252.8278).

I now need to calculate the time in seconds from the start (1891 seconds) to the first OD value that exceed the +/- threshold values. For example for the above data frame this threshold is exceeded at 1895 seconds corresponding to an OD of -253.9.

I now have to repeat this 3 times for each study subject and 17 subjects overall, thus, I am looking for a function where I can define the data frame and the threshold values, and it will return the first OD value where it exceeds the defined thresholds (all_threshold$sup_2_minus) and (all_threshold$sup_2_plus) and its corresponding time.

I have tried `subset` a advised elsewhere:

```
subset(lbnp_br, lbnp_br$OD < all_threshold$sup_2_minus & lbnp_br$OD > all_threshold$sup_2_plus)
```

However, this doesn't return what I am looking for.

and also

```
ifelse(lbnp_br$OD > all_threshold$sup_2_plus & lbnp_br$OD < all_threshold$sup_2_minus, lbnp_br$OD, NA)
```

which returns NA and doesn't specify the exact value of OD and the time.

Comment: use `which` with `[1]`  where is the `all_threshold` data

Comment: `function (dfr) dfr[min(which(dfr$OD > threshold)), ]`

Answer (score 1):

A one liner:

```
function (dfr, threshold) dfr$OD[ min(which(dfr$OD > threshold)) ]
```

Gives a warning and `NA` if there is no such row in the data frame, which is probably what you want.

An alternative, `purrr`-based solution:

```
function (dfr, threshold) purrr::detect(dfr$OD, ~ .x > threshold)
```

which returns `NULL` if nothing is found, more correct I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a short answer, but hopefully clear.  It uses the dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)

find_time = function(df, threshold){
  return_value = df %>%
    arrange(time) %>%
    filter(OD < threshold) %>%
    slice(1)
  return(return_value)
}

find_time(data, threshold)
```

This will sort (arrange) your data based on time, subset (filter) your data for values of OD below the threshold, take the first value (slice), and return it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the above code, I added a few extra conditions to get exactly what I was looking for and here it is for anyone who may need something similar:

```
find_time <- function(df, df2, df3, threshold_1, threshold_2, threshold_3, threshold_4, threshold_5, threshold_6){
  return_value_1 = df %>%
    arrange(time) %>%
    filter(OD > threshold_1) %>%
    slice_(1)
  colnames(return_value_1)[1] <- "time_hdt_upper"
  colnames(return_value_1)[2] <- "OD_hdt_upper"

  if (nrow(return_value_1) == 0) {
    return_value_1[1,1] <- NA
    return_value_1[1,2] <- NA
  }


  return_value_2 = df %>%
    arrange(time) %>%
    filter(OD < threshold_2) %>%
    slice_(1)
  colnames(return_value_2)[1] <- "time_hdt_lower"
  colnames(return_value_2)[2] <- "OD_hdt_lower"

  if (nrow(return_value_2) == 0) {
    return_value_2[1,1] <- NA
    return_value_2[1,2] <- NA
  }

  return_value_3 = df2 %>%
    arrange(time) %>%
    filter(OD > threshold_3) %>%
    slice_(1)
  colnames(return_value_3)[1] <- "time_lbnp_upper"
  colnames(return_value_3)[2] <- "OD_lbnp_upper"

  if (nrow(return_value_3) == 0) {
    return_value_3[1,1] <- NA
    return_value_3[1,2] <- NA
  }


  return_value_4 = df2 %>%
    arrange(time) %>%
    filter(OD < threshold_4) %>%
    slice_(1)
  colnames(return_value_4)[1] <- "time_lbnp_lower"
  colnames(return_value_4)[2] <- "OD_lbnp_lower"

  if (nrow(return_value_4) == 0) {
    return_value_4[1,1] <- NA
    return_value_4[1,2] <- NA
  }



  return_value_5 = df3 %>%
    arrange(time) %>%
    filter(OD > threshold_5) %>%
    slice_(1)
  colnames(return_value_5)[1] <- "time_hut_upper"
  colnames(return_value_5)[2] <- "OD_hut_upper"

  if (nrow(return_value_5) == 0) {
    return_value_5[1,1] <- NA
    return_value_5[1,2] <- NA
  }



  return_value_6 = df3 %>%
    arrange(time) %>%
    filter(OD < threshold_6) %>%
    slice_(1)
  colnames(return_value_6)[1] <- "time_hut_lower"
  colnames(return_value_6)[2] <- "OD_hut_lower"

  if (nrow(return_value_6) == 0) {
    return_value_6[1,1] <- NA
    return_value_6[1,2] <- NA
  }



  return(data.frame(return_value_1, return_value_2, return_value_3, return_value_4, return_value_5, return_value_6))


}
```

## which gives

```
find_time_threshold <- find_time(hdt_br, lbnp_br, hut_br, all_threshold$base_plus, all_threshold$base_minus, all_threshold$sup_2_plus, all_threshold$sup_2_minus, all_threshold$sup_3_plus, all_threshold$sup_3_minus)
> find_time_threshold

  time_hdt_upper OD_hdt_upper time_hdt_lower OD_hdt_lower time_lbnp_upper OD_lbnp_upper time_lbnp_lower
1          596.5        123.3            506         91.3              NA            NA            1706
  OD_lbnp_lower time_hut_upper OD_hut_upper time_hut_lower OD_hut_lower
1        -27.89         3186.5       -82.98           2909       -211.7
```